# Azure App Insights Latency and Overhead

Tags: performance, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm interested in using Azure Application Insights in an ASP.NET project I am working on, but I am curious as to the potential impact to performance caused running both the client-side and server-side telemetry.

What is the a rule of thumb or guide regarding potential impact of App Insights?

Comment: I know that, at least server side, telemetry is collected and send in batches in a background process to minimize impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application Insights .NET SDK uses adaptive sampling in default configuration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sampling). It guarantees that app instance will not upload more than 5 documents/sec.

As @Peter Bons noted, Application Insights SDK uploads documents in batches in background and tries not to intervene with app's flow.

Internally we run services with 3K RPS/instance instrumented with AI SKD in default configuration.

Your mileage might vary - the overhead depends on what a web service is doing.